# Create time based events using Spark / Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

We are working on the timeseries data and we need to create time based events based on the timeseries values.

Below is the sample input Hive table.

```
PointId Timestamp   Value
P1  1/1/2017 0:03   3
P1  1/1/2017 0:09   3
P1  1/1/2017 0:38   3
P2  1/1/2017 0:01   5
P2  1/1/2017 0:05   5
P2  1/1/2017 0:27   21
P2  1/1/2017 0:33   5
```

I want to create events based on the timestamp. Output should be something like this

```
PointId Start Event End Event   Value
P1  1/1/2017 0:03   1/1/2017 0:38   3
P2  1/1/2017 0:01   1/1/2017 0:05   5
P2  1/1/2017 0:05   1/1/2017 0:27   21
P2  1/1/2017 0:27   1/1/2017 0:33   5
```

I can use Hive, Spark Core, SparkSQL for the implementation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post more events from `P1` as it may not be clear enough to offer you help. The best would be to see what should happen when `P1` appears after `P2` in the sample with `Value` being 3 or 21.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski  philantrovert's solution is correct. That is what we want

Comment: It doesn't look like it can be partitioned. What if `P1` appears after the last `P2` ?

Comment: we can sort the data based on pointid and timestamp before partitioning